# The problem of surds and indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$ \frac 12 \times \left(\sqrt[3] a + \sqrt[3] b + \sqrt[3] c\right) = \frac 1{\sqrt[3] 3 - 1}\;\;\;(a>b>c)$$

then what is  $a - 2b - 3c $ ?

Comment: Do you want $a^{1/3}$ or $\frac{a}{3}$

Comment: $a[1/3] sorry but I can't write properly here

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt[3] a$ and so on?  If so, I'll edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yeap (1/3) is power of a,b and c

Comment: I have tried to edit your question, please check to see that I did not change your meaning.  A good tutorial on formatting can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Exactly that's it....I'm sorry for troubling you...thank you very much

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ intended to be positive integers, or any reals? If reals then the equation is in three vars so expect a two parameter set of solution, and unless something magical happens, would not expect $a-2b-3c$ to be determined.

Comment: Positive integers

Comment: user341135 Such a restriction should be placed in the question itself so nobody needs to refer to comments for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the factorization $x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$ with $x = \sqrt[3]{3}$ to get $2 = (\sqrt[3]{3}-1)(\sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} + 1)$, or

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}-1} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt[3]{9}+\sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt[3]{1})$$

So $a = 9$, $b = 3$, $c = 1$.

Comment: Does this prove no other solutions (in positive integers)?

Comment: @coffeemath, it is possilbe that the OP needs any solution, not every solution

Comment: @coffeemath No, it doesn't. This is the kind of problem that would appear on a standardized test, where you just need to get the right form and identify the values. That's how I answered the question.